# SQL Search performance in 2 columns vs combined 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, query-optimization, denormalization

Using an MSSQL Server stored procedure, short table structure is

```
Id int, --PK
Code varchar(20),   --Indexed column
Oems varchar(max)   --Some rows will have thousands of oems
```

There are 500K records, every row has a Code. 400k rows have Oems. Sample data

```
Id   Code         Oems
-------------------------------------
1   ARD5612     ,7171833,B716382,324324,2423423,GB23434,00002334
2   80001627    ,99901811,1727282,...
```

Current condition is (**find all** and only beginning of the key must match)

```
WHERE code LIKE @Key + '%' OR Oems LIKE '%,' + @Key + '%'

Key = 1234
Code = 123456 Find
Code = 001234 don’t find
Oems = ,12340000,kh77,062483 find
Oems = ,7777,5262,abc723,x1234 don’t find
```

So, my question is that should I combine these two columns and make the search over one single column or leave it as it is?

Does having an index on the `Code` column have a positive affect on search at all?

Thank you

Edit: As many suggested, if I convert Oems into a new table, that table will have 15M records.
How is the new design will help performance?

Thanks

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems.

Comment: Definitely index if you're searching 400 or 500 000 lines using this column.

Comment: It seems like you want to search by the first characters of the OEM. It would be greatlybeneficial if you have the chance of changing the database design, and store each OEM on a separate row.

Comment: By the way `Oems like ‘,’+@Key+’%’` will only find the row with the OEMs in the first place only; the second, third, etc. are ignored. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: An index isn't going to help with a wildcard search, unless the wildcard is only at the end. This is one of the many reasons you should change your table design

Comment: Thank you that was a typo. So converting oems into a new table with 15 million records would work better than comma separated values?

Comment: Yes, more rows with a single `OEM` per row will allow you to use an index on `OEM` to quickly find (via and index seek) either an exact match or a "starts with" match, e.g. `OEM like '42%;`. Matches later in the string, e.g. `like '%42%'` will not use an index _seek_, nor will `like '%42'`. They might benefit from an index _scan_, but only to the extent that the index can be read faster than the complete rows. You can also add a constraint to preclude having an OEM associated more than once with a single `Code`, whereas the current schema allows for `OEMS` to be `'42,42,42,7,42`.

Comment: Thank you. I think the best approach will be then; having 15 million rows and creating two separate indexes  on Code and Oems columns and use the same where clause.

Comment: I mean,  WHERE code LIKE Key + '%' OR Oems LIKE Key + '%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I inserted comma separated values into a new table with one value in each row, added an index and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).